# Hotkey to switch between debug tabs in Intelij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I have several debug tabs in Intelij IDEA:
[image: Debug tabs]

If I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> IDEA suggests me to open another opened files.
Is there any hotkey to switch between debug tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd>. And it works in any window which has tabs (Project View, Editor, terminal, etc.)

You can see it in **Settings** -> **Keymap** then **Main menu** -> **Window** -> **Editor Tabs**: **Select Previous/Next Tab**

[image]